# Moderated messages on SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, message-queue, messaging, amazon-sqs

I have a messaging use case question.

We have a queue in AWS SQS, say, ***origQueue*** and ***out-of-the-box-lambda-based-message-consumption*** on that queue.

Now to cater to one particular feature of moderation based message consumption (on the basis of a 'isModerated' flag within the message), I am thinking to have another parallel queue (which would just be a moderated version of the above queue). On this 'moderated' queue, we don't want automatic consumption, rather we are looking for a moderated step trigger based consumption. That means any lambda will not be listening to this queue all the time.

One thought I had is to trigger a lambda at runtime (after moderation is done) which will basically de-queue from the moderated queue, remove the 'isModerated' flag from the messages and re-queue them in the actual queue, i.e. ***origQueue***.

But before going that way, I just wanted to gather other potential ideas.  Is there any out-of-the-box AWS feature or any pattern to solve this trigger based message consumption problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the messages are entering the queue from SNS, you might be able to use message filtering before they get queued:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html

Comment: I was avoiding SNS because my use case was simply a producer-consumer problem. 'fan-out' is not required. Introducing SNS just for message filtering would not be an overkill?

Comment: Perhaps, but it makes sense to decouple the producer from the consumer with SNS in many circumstances and it would allow you to do the filtering. It also means you can change queues, add multiple queues (one moderated, one not) or whatever design you want without having to modify the producer code (i.e. SNS is responsible for handling the consumers).

Comment: I am convinced, having a SNS might help in the long term as well. Thanks!